# Sublime won't open with terminal

Tags: text, terminal, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to open up sublime through the terminal but it won't open

Here is the code

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

When I try to open it with subl `.bash_profile`

I get this error

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

does anybody know why????

Comment: did you do a `source .bash_profile` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your terminal window and re-open it for changes to take effect. Or you can run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This will allow the change to take place without restarting your tty session.

Comment: Its still not working. maybe I messed up somewhere. could I take the file out and redo it again?

Comment: Do you see subl symlink in `/usr/local/bin`? If not, please make sure you follow the syntax (note the quotes) at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

If that looks okay, I would reboot your computer.

Comment: It still didn't work. I installed textmate 2 and it worked perfectly so I guess Ill just work with that.